Virtual Console Login Loop (non-GUI)
As I type this, in my Netrunner Debian 12 KDE system, if I hit for example Ctrl-Alt-F3, it gives a terminal login prompt.

I can't get past that prompt. If I type the username and password correctly, it just clears the screen and shows the terminal login prompt again.
I can still go back to the GUI using Ctrl-Alt-F7 to keep typing this question.

Any suggestions where to look?

/var/log/syslog contains this after doing that:
2024-11-27T18:59:14.388452-08:00 RzT470Netrunner systemd[1]: Started session-1623.scope - Session 1623 of User rinzin.
2024-11-27T18:59:14.394477-08:00 RzT470Netrunner wireplumber[1500]: SPA handle 'api.bluez5.enum.dbus' could not be loaded; is it installed?
2024-11-27T18:59:14.394688-08:00 RzT470Netrunner wireplumber[1500]: PipeWire's BlueZ SPA missing or broken. Bluetooth not supported.
2024-11-27T18:59:14.396358-08:00 RzT470Netrunner systemd[1]: getty@tty3.service: Deactivated successfully.
2024-11-27T18:59:14.410998-08:00 RzT470Netrunner systemd[1]: session-1623.scope: Deactivated successfully.
2024-11-27T18:59:14.411962-08:00 RzT470Netrunner systemd[1]: getty@tty3.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 3.
2024-11-27T18:59:14.412850-08:00 RzT470Netrunner systemd[1]: Stopped getty@tty3.service - Getty on tty3.
2024-11-27T18:59:14.436539-08:00 RzT470Netrunner systemd[1]: Started getty@tty3.service - Getty on tty3.
2024-11-27T18:59:16.025507-08:00 RzT470Netrunner rtkit-daemon[1392]: Supervising 0 threads of 0 processes of 0 users.
2024-11-27T18:59:16.034408-08:00 RzT470Netrunner rtkit-daemon[1392]: Supervising 0 threads of 0 processes of 0 users.
2024-11-27T18:59:20.238554-08:00 RzT470Netrunner wireplumber[1500]: SPA handle 'api.bluez5.enum.dbus' could not be loaded; is it installed?
2024-11-27T18:59:20.239586-08:00 RzT470Netrunner wireplumber[1500]: PipeWire's BlueZ SPA missing or broken. Bluetooth not supported.
2024-11-27T18:59:21.834857-08:00 RzT470Netrunner kded5[531489]: Initializing  "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/plasma/kcms/systemsettings/kcm_mouse.so"
2024-11-27T18:59:21.872833-08:00 RzT470Netrunner kded5[531489]: Initializing  "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/plasma/kcms/systemsettings/kcm_touchpad.so"
2024-11-27T18:59:21.872895-08:00 RzT470Netrunner kded5[531489]: kcm_touchpad: Using X11 backend
2024-11-27T18:59:21.874708-08:00 RzT470Netrunner kded5[531489]: Width:  3794  height:  3036
2024-11-27T18:59:21.874761-08:00 RzT470Netrunner kded5[531489]: Approx. resX:  42  resY:  60
2024-11-27T18:59:21.874822-08:00 RzT470Netrunner kded5[531489]: Touchpad resolution: x:  45  y:  54
2024-11-27T18:59:21.874863-08:00 RzT470Netrunner kded5[531489]: Final resolution x: 45  y: 54
2024-11-27T18:59:21.881830-08:00 RzT470Netrunner kwin_x11[1794]: qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 43603, resource id: 153092101, major code: 18 (ChangeProperty), minor code: 0


And with journalctl -r I find this:
Nov 27 19:22:21 RzT470Netrunner login[532343]: Permission denied
Nov 27 19:22:21 RzT470Netrunner login[532343]: gkr-pam: couldn't unlock the login keyring.





Can you successfully log in as root, or as any other user? 2) What login shell do you use, according to lslogins USERNAME? 3) If it's bash – do you have anything new in ~/.profile, ~/.bash_profile, or ~/.bashrc?


Thank you. 1) No. Logging in as root is the same - just reverts to the login prompt. 2) Yes, bash  3) This isn't a new problem, but ~/.profile has very little in it. No ~/.bash_profile. ~/.bashrc is long. I'm not sure whether I've ever messed with it.  I tried renaming it so it wouldn't be found, but that doesn't help.

The part about unable to unlock the login keyring seems to be irrelevant - just a notice, really: link

In /var/log/auth.log I found this:
PAM _pam_load_conf_file: unable to open config for /etc/pam.d/system-local-login

And, indeed, that file is missing. Googling it, I found a template file here:
https://github.com/coreos/baselayout/tree/master/pam.d
Upon creating the file, and trying again, auth.log then reported another missing file from that folder. Repeat. Then a third. So all together, I needed to create (or download) the following three files from that URL above:
/etc/pam.d/system-auth
/etc/pam.d/system-local-login
/etc/pam.d/system-login

Now I can log in again on the virtual consoles Ctrl-Alt-F1 through F6!
